# Exception of invocation on the mock was 0 times, but I can see performed invocations correctly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, autofixture

Here's my simplified version of unit test

```
var service = Fixture.Freeze<IService>();
var outerService = Fixture.Create<OuterService>();

var testObject = Fixture.Create<TestObject>();

outerService.Notify(testObject);
Mock.Get(service).Verify(s => s.SendNotification(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<TestObject>(), null), Times.Once);
```

Note that:

`outerService.Notify(testObject)`

internally calls

`IService.SendNotification(string testObject.Name, testObject, extraObject = null)`

---

The above will cause the test to fail, complaining that:

```
Expected invocation 1 time,but was 0 times: 
s => s.SendNotification(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<TestObject>(), null)
No setups configured.

Performed invocations:
IService.SendNotification("testObject", UnitTest.TestObject, null)
```

I don't understand, the performed invocation looks exactly like the expected invocation, what is going on here?

---

### EDIT

Ok so it is working if I call `service.SendNotification` **directly** in the test, but it won't work if I call it via `outerService`? Why?

---

### UPDATE

Apologies if my question was not clear enough, here's some more details as to how the `Fixture` object is configured:

```
Fixture fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());
fixture.Customize(new SpecimenCustomization());
```

That is really about it for the details, it's hopefully not a complicated scenario I suppose.

Comment: You will get that error when `The received mocked instance was not created by Moq`

Comment: How can we reproduce this issue? From the code shown, it looks like `Fixture` is some sort of property. How is it created? How is it configured? With an unconfigured `Fixture` object, you'd get a completely different exception than the one you report. Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thanks for pointing it out, I've provided more details in the question. If any more details are required, please kindly let me know

Comment: What's `SpecimenCustomization`? Is it necessary to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error occurs when you call `Mock.Get` and `The received mocked instance was not created by Moq`. That means that there were `No setups configured` for the mocked service.

Given this simplified assumption.

```
public class OuterService {
    private IService service;

    public OuterService(IService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void Notify(TestObject testObject) {
        service.SendNotification(testObject.Name, testObject, extraObject: null);
    }
}

public interface IService {
    void SendNotification(string name, TestObject testObject, object extraObject);
}

public class TestObject {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The following test should work

```
//Arrange
var service = Mock.Of<IService>();
var outerService = new OuterService(service);
var testObject = new TestObject { Name = "testObject" };

//Act
outerService.Notify(testObject);

//Assert
Mock.Get(service).Verify(s => s.SendNotification(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<TestObject>(), null), Times.Once);
```

Moq is now aware of the service object and can extract the mock setup from the mocked instance created above.

### Update:

Realized you were using **AutoFixture** and after some research was able to recreate your problem. You need to customize **AutoFixture** to use **Moq**.

Check [Auto-Mocking with Moq](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#auto-mocking-with-moq) on how to do that.

The following then worked given the same assumptions stated above.

```
//Arrange
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(new Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoMoq.AutoMoqCustomization());

var service = fixture.Freeze<IService>();
var outerService = fixture.Create<OuterService>();
var testObject = fixture.Create<TestObject>();

//Act
outerService.Notify(testObject);

//Assert
Mock.Get(service).Verify(s => s.SendNotification(It.IsAny<String>(), It.IsAny<TestObject>(), null), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Hey Nkosi, thank you so much for your detailed answer, I very much appreciate it (+1). Unfortunately following your suggestion still produces the same result, complaining about `No setups configured`. Would you happen to have any other ideas?

Comment: I tried with both `fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomisation())` and `new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`, none of them is working

Comment: Hi Nkosi, So it seems like Mock is able to recognise my `service` object, because the test will pass if I call `service.SendNotification` directly. So it must be an issue with `outerService` not being picked up by Mock?

Comment: I really don't have any other ideas as I got it to work using the suggestions I gave and didn't look into anything else as I thought that would have solved your problem. It is very strange. Unfortunate that my suggestion didn't resolve your issue. Did you try my first suggestion without using AutoFixture to see if it would work?

Comment: No I haven't tried your first solution, although I think it will work I just wanted to know why my code is not working with AutoFixture. I am maintaining a legacy project with hundreds of unit tests written like this with AutoFixture, and this seems to be the only one that causes trouble. Anyways thank you for your time to look into this, I will mark this as answer if no one else comes up with a solution in two days. Cheers!